# Unable to get user's email with Parse Facebook login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm using Parse and I'm trying to create a simple facebook login.
My FB initializtion looks like:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({ // this line replaces FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Facebook App ID
      status     : true,  // check Facebook Login status
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // initialize Facebook social plugins on the page
      version    : 'v2.3' // point to the latest Facebook Graph API version
    });
};
```

and my FB login function looks like:

```
Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('email', {
      success: function(user) {
        if (!user.existed()) {
          alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");              
        } else {
          alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
});
```

The flow works great as I can see the user is created (on first login) in Parse core view (Users table) and I can see Parse.User.current() is the FB user.
The thing is, **I cannot find the user's email...**
I have tried:

```
Parse.User.current().getEmail(); //undefined
FB.api('/me', function(me) { console.log(me) }); //prints an object with 'name' and 'id' fields only
```

and nothing works....
In addition, I have tried null/'email'/'public_profile,email' as the first FB login argument, without success... :(

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(me) { console.log(me) });
```

It´s called "Declarative Fields": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

If that does not work, then there´s probably something wrong with the login. Make sure you get asked for the email permission.

Comment: That works for me! This is strange... I would expect Parse to wrap a decent API for getting FB fields... or that currUser.getEmail() will return the email. anyways - thanks so much!